# DataView Webpart Folders

Tags: web-part, xslt, data-view-web-part, query

Is there a way to pass the root folder parameter to a page that the DataView webpart consumes?

If I have a page, test.aspx with a DVWP on it, it will show all my documents and folders in a list. If I click on the document, it opens it. If I click the folder, it jumps me to the list where the DVWP sources it's data.

What I really want is to format the XSL in a way so that instead of jumping to the list, it just goes back to the ASPX with a parameter. I've tried a bunch and can't find the right one. The Webpart does not expose a url that would work.

I would expect it to be something like Test.aspx?RootFolder=/ or something like that.

Is this possible?